# How do I use Pytorch's "tanslation with a seq2seq" using my own inputs?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, pytorch, data-science, seq2seq

I am following the guide [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/seq2seq_translation_tutorial.html)

Currently this is the model:

```
SOS_token = 0
EOS_token = 1


class Lang:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.word2index = {}
        self.word2count = {}
        self.index2word = {0: "SOS", 1: "EOS"}
        self.n_words = 2  # Count SOS and EOS

    def addSentence(self, sentence):
        for word in sentence.split(' '):
            self.addWord(word)

    def addWord(self, word):
        if word not in self.word2index:
            self.word2index[word] = self.n_words
            self.word2count[word] = 1
            self.index2word[self.n_words] = word
            self.n_words += 1
        else:
            self.word2count[word] += 1
def unicodeToAscii(s):
    return ''.join(
        c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s)
        if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'
    )

# Lowercase, trim, and remove non-letter characters


def normalizeString(s):
    s = unicodeToAscii(s.lower().strip())
    s = re.sub(r"([.!?])", r" \1", s)
    s = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z.!?]+", r" ", s)
    return s
def readLangs(lang1, lang2, reverse=False):
    print("Reading lines...")

    # Read the file and split into lines
    lines = open('Scribe/%s-%s.txt' % (lang1, lang2), encoding='utf-8').\
        read().strip().split('\n')

    # Split every line into pairs and normalize
    pairs = [[normalizeString(s) for s in l.split('\t')] for l in lines]

    # Reverse pairs, make Lang instances
    if reverse:
        pairs = [list(reversed(p)) for p in pairs]
        input_lang = Lang(lang2)
        output_lang = Lang(lang1)
    else:
        input_lang = Lang(lang1)
        output_lang = Lang(lang2)

    return input_lang, output_lang, pair
MAX_LENGTH = 5000

eng_prefixes = (
    "i am ", "i m ",
    "he is", "he s ",
    "she is", "she s ",
    "you are", "you re ",
    "we are", "we re ",
    "they are", "they re "
)


def filterPair(p):
    return len(p[0].split(' ')) < MAX_LENGTH and \
        len(p[1].split(' ')) < MAX_LENGTH and \
        p[1].startswith(eng_prefixes)


def filterPairs(pairs):
    return [pair for pair in pairs if filterPair(pair)]
def prepareData(lang1, lang2, reverse=False):
    input_lang, output_lang, pairs = readLangs(lang1, lang2, reverse)
    print("Read %s sentence pairs" % len(pairs))
    pairs = filterPairs(pairs)
    print("Trimmed to %s sentence pairs" % len(pairs))
    print("Counting words...")
    for pair in pairs:
        input_lang.addSentence(pair[0])
        output_lang.addSentence(pair[1])
    print("Counted words:")
    print(input_lang.name, input_lang.n_words)
    print(output_lang.name, output_lang.n_words)
    return input_lang, output_lang, pairs
```

The difference between what I'm trying to do and the guide is that I'm trying  to insert my input languages as list of strings instead of reading them from a file:

```
pairs=['string one goes like this', 'string two goes like this'] 
input_lang = Lang(pairs[0][0])
output_lang = Lang(pairs[1][1])
```

But I it seems like when I try to count the number of words `input_lang.n_words` in my string I always get 2.

Is there something I'm missing in calling the class `Lang`?

Update:
I ran

```
language = Lang('english')

for sentence in pairs: language.addSentence(sentence)

print (language.n_words)
```

and that gave me the number of words in `pairs`
Though, that doesn't give me `input_lang` and `output_lang` like the guide did:

```
for pair in pairs:
    input_lang.addSentence(pair[0])
    output_lang.addSentence(pair[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of all you are initialising the `Lang` object with calls to `pairs[0][0]` and `pairs[1][1]` which is the same as `Lang('s')` and `Lang('t')`

The `Lang` object is supposed to be an object that stores information about a language so I would expect you need to only initialise it once with `Lang('english')` and then add the sentences from you dataset to the `Lang` object with the `Lang.addSentence` function.

Right now you aren't loading your dataset into the `Lang` object at all so when you want to know `language.n_words` it is just the initial value it gets when the object is created `self.n_words = 2  # Count SOS and EOS`

None of what you are doing in your question makes any sense, but I think what you want is the following:

```
language = Lang('english')

for sentence in pairs: language.addSentence(sentence)

print (language.n_words)
```

Comment: I'm not really sure where you got the 'english' part, but it did give me the number of words in 'pairs'. Please see my update above